# Hyperlink like plots in R

Tags: r, plot, hyperlink, linegraph

Is there a package in R where if you have a line graph, and you click on one of the lines, it will take you to another graph?

So basically I want to portray a large scale view of paramters and then when I click on one of the lines in the graph, it will take me to a more detailed look at the data in a different graph created.

If that isn't possible, then a text hyperlink in the legend would be fantastic.

Thanks!

Comment: Would you be OK using Shiny? It sounds like the tool you need. http://shiny.rstudio.com/

Comment: I've never used it before but if it is an easy learning curve I'm sure I can figure it out @nico

Comment: I'd say: have a look at the [gallery](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/) and see if you can get some inspiration. If you are familiar with R then using Shiny is a breeze. The only thing is I think you require using RStudio to use shiny (not 100% sure though).

Comment: It's not exactly what you ask for, but the function `dygraph` from the `dygraphs` package might be interesting for you. See `example(dygraph)`.

Comment: Thanks @nico I use RStudio already so I will look further into that.

Comment: @user2706569 Thanks for the recommendation, I had some trouble downloading that package but will look further into it